# Eclipse bug when using StatET and Shift+Alt+A

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

`Shift+Alt+A` is used to highlight vertically or rectanguarly. I am trying to use it with `StatET` (R code) but have run into some issues.

If I used `Shift+Alt+A` to put a column of brackets `(`,`)`,`[`,`]` in my code, then all code will get deleted in the concerned rows.

If I switch to a `py` or `java` file, the issue disappears.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I  have the same problem! But why just for these character!!

Comment: It is better to send this problem to STATET mailing list.